# Discord Joining User account bot

Tags: javascript, bots, discord, discord.js

A couple months ago I made a bot that joins the discord with the invite link i give and then spamms the message in the specific channel and it worked really good but now with the same code I am getting strange error {"message": "404: Not Found", "code": 0} NOT FOUND 404

Did something change? How to fix that?

```
const Discord = require('discord.js') 
const settings = require("./settings.json");
const client = new Discord.Client();

var prompt = require('prompt');
const request = require('request');


prompt.start()

prompt.get(['invite', 'MSG', 'ID'], function (err, result) {


  var invite = result.invite;
  var MSG = result.MSG
  var ID = result.ID


  request.post(`https://discordapp.com/api/invites/${invite}`, {
    headers: {
      "Authorization": settings.token    
    }
  }, (error, response, body) => {
    if(error) {
      console.log(error);
      return;
    }
    console.log(body, response.statusMessage, response.statusCode);
  })


  client.on('message', (msg) => {
    if(msg.content != "stop"){
      var chanel  = client.channels.get(ID)
      chanel.send(MSG)
    }
  })



  client.login(settings.token) 

})
```

Comment: Is that all of the error that you are getting?

Answer (score 1):

You made a spam selfbot that breaks discord ToS.

The error message is the result of the bot account being banned, it no longer has access to the API, thus 404.